# how to overcome the limit of scraping data from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to the concept of scraping data off the internet and need some help.

I am using python 3.6.1 to scrape product details from Paytm(e-commerce website in India).

I am using the following webpage url to scrape the data
https://paytm.com/shop/g/electronics/computers-accessories/computer-components/laptop-adapters?src=1&q=graphic%20card

Problem: The website contains 49 products in a page but i am able to scrape only 30 products. I have also tried for webpage containing mobile phones on the paytm but still i am able to scrape only 30 whereas number of phones in page is 128.

My python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
my_url='https://paytm.com/shop/g/electronics/mobile-accessories/mobiles/smart-phones?src=1&q=mobile%20phones'
page=ureq(my_url).read()
page_soup=soup(page,"html.parser")
containers=page_soup.find_all("div",{"class":"_2i1r"})
print(len(containers))
f=open("paytm_mobiles.csv","w")
f.write("Product_Name, Amount\n")

for i in containers:
    name=i.find_all("div",{"class":"_2apC"})
    print("Name :" + name[0].text)
    price=i.findAll("span", {'class':"_1kMS"})
    print("Price :"+ price[0].text)
    f.write(name[0].text.replace("."," ")+","+price[0].text+"\n")

f.close()
```

Please help me to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple get request and call Json from the actual endpoint - also note I did up the `items_per_page` parameter to 40 , usually you can extend it way more, but for some strange reason - if I go higher than 40, it just sets back to 30... anyway here is a sample

```
import requests


query = '/g/electronics/mobile-accessories/mobiles/smart-phones?q=mobile%20phones'
currentPage = 1
totalCount = 50
while currentPage <= totalCount / 40:
    currentPage += 1
    url = 'https://catalog.paytm.com/v1'+ query + '&channel=web&page_count=' + str(currentPage) + '&items_per_page=40'
    resultsPage = requests.get(url).json()
    totalCount = resultsPage['totalCount']
    for gridResult in resultsPage['grid_layout']:
        title = gridResult['name']
        price = gridResult['actual_price']
        print("Product Name: " + title + '\nPrice: ' + str(price))
        print('\n')
```

The only parts that you need to change based on what your search is, is the query portion, the rest of the URL will stay the same and it will automatically know how many pages to go through since the totalCount is at the bottom of the object to begin with.

[image]

Comment: what value should I initialize to totalCount as i am getting following error. Traceback (most recent call last):
    while currentPage <= totalCount / 40:
NameError: name 'totalCount' is not defined

Comment: Sorry I forgot I had moved the total count down lower - you can just initialize it up higher to any number above 1 because as soon as it fetches the real data it will update itself to the correct value

Comment: Thanks a lot mam.

Comment: Mam, Your code scrapped 1119 products whereas actual products are 1159. And i am missing 30 products that where scrapped from my code. Could you please fix this for me.

Answer (score 1):

In this page at the time of loading only contain a 30 products. After scroll down products are append by ajax call. So using BeautifulSoup you can only get 30 product.

Comment: can you please help me to get other?

Comment: correct. @sachinrathod there's no simple way to do it with BeautifulSoup or any othter scraper.  You have to rely on some APIs from the web server to get more (or paginated) results.  Ask the author of the website if some API are available.

Comment: @MuthurajS do you mean BeautifulSoup allows only 30 products to scrape on any eCommerce website.

Comment: No, Beautiful Soup can extract all product in response.

Comment: @MuthurajS sachin rathod didn't mean the BeautifulSoup only scraps 30 from an ecommerce website. BeautifulSoup loads data using requests library, so when you get the content, it only has 30 products on the website. The other contents are loaded dynamically when you scroll down. Since beautifulSoup captures data at the beginning, even if the content changes on the the website , it won't affect the data, since it has already been captured when you did `requests.get(...)`